# Angular not interpolating value in array index

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat in which I would like the repeated value to be used as the array index value.

Controller:

```
vm.ingredientsCount = [0,1,2];
```

Template

```
<div ng-repeat="count in vm.ingredientsCount">
            <h3>Ingredients {{count}} {{$index}}</h3>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index]" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index]"> </formly-form>
            <h4>Ingredients Quantity</h4>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index].quantity" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index].quantity"> </formly-form>
</div>
```

In the rendered HTML `{{count}}` and `{{index}}` are interpolated correctly, but anything `[$index]` or `[{{$index}}]` will not interpolate.

Rendered HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="count in vm.ingredientsCount">
        <h3>Ingredients 0 0</h3>
        <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index]" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index]"> </formly-form>
        <h4>Ingredients Quantity</h4>
        <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index].quantity" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index].quantity"> </formly-form>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="count in vm.ingredientsCount">
            <h3>Ingredients 1 1</h3>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index]" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index]"> </formly-form>
            <h4>Ingredients Quantity</h4>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index].quantity" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index].quantity"> </formly-form>
    </div>

<div ng-repeat="count in vm.ingredientsCount">
            <h3>Ingredients 2 2</h3>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index]" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index]"> </formly-form>
            <h4>Ingredients Quantity</h4>
            <formly-form model="vm.model.ingredients[$index].quantity" fields="vm.fields.ingredients[$index].quantity"> </formly-form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your `vm.model.ingredients` data?

Comment: WHat does `won't interpolate` mean exactly? What is happening? What do the arrays look like?

Comment: I've added the rendered html to my question to help clarify.

Comment: It wont interpolate because you have not used interpolation. Regardless it should give the right model based on the index. doesn't it?

Comment: no, it doesn't, it just renders out $index instead of the value of $index

Comment: `[{{$index}}]` this doesn't make sense... it should probably be something like: `{{ vm.model.ingredients[$index] }}`

Comment: [$index] is what would make sense to me, however that is rendering exactly as it is in the template, as [$index]. So far ['{{$index}}'] does interpolate as ['0'], ['1']...but that gives me the string value instead of [0] and [1]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what formly-form is doing, but based on your last comment of `$index` being spat out and `[{{$index}}]` not working. The solution is to have this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="count in vm.ingredientsCount">
    <h3>Ingredients {{count}} {{$index}}</h3>
    <formly-form model="{{ vm.model.ingredients[$index] }}" fields="{{ vm.fields.ingredients[$index] }}"> </formly-form>
    <h4>Ingredients Quantity</h4>
    <formly-form model="{{ vm.model.ingredients[$index].quantity }}" fields="{{ vm.fields.ingredients[$index].quantity }}"> </formly-form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I currently have in my template, which is not working. I've left an additional comment on the question.